# resource size for different densities in android

Tags: android, multiscreen

i have made images for an mdpi phone in android. 
i want to resize those images for hdpi and ldpi screens.
what is the conversion factor for the dimesions? i have heard that we multiply the height and width of the mdpi image by 1.5 to convert it to a hdpi screen.
what is the accurate conversion factor- for both mdpi to hpdi and mdpi to ldpi?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), 0.75 for ldpi, 1.0 for mdpi and 1.5 for hdpi. Note that if you specified the measurements in dp ( density-independent pixels ), Android will take care of the scaling for you.

> It scales 1.5 times if the target
>   density is high density (160->240
>   virtual dpi), or 0.75 times if the
>   target density is low density (160 ->
>   120 virtual dpi).

You could also scale it in the coding, by retrieving the current density and multiply them.

```
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // retrieve current density

newImageWidth = currentImageWidth * scale;
```

[This is a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638202/android-multiple-screen-sizes-with-same-density) regarding density.