# Multiple Screen?

Tags: java, android, screen

Well I'm developed the android app and i confused in Screen Size , can anyone explanation these words for me please , i mean for example `WVGA` can we use in which kind of Layout folder ? `layout-small` , `layout-large` ... ?

```
layout= ? size (WVGA , QVGA ...)        
layout-small= ? size  (WVGA , QVGA ...)     
layout-large= ? size (WVGA , QVGA ...)     
layout-large-long= ? size  (WVGA , QVGA ...)    
layout-large-land=? size (WVGA , QVGA ...)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you take a look here? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: you can also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638202/android-multiple-screen-sizes-with-same-density

Answer (score 1):

Check the Android Developer page about [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

Theses Android developer resources have all the information you need regarding screen sizes and densities:

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html