# Layout resources for tablets

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I'm busy developing an android application by making use of Xamarin and Visual Studio. I have created the following folder structure:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

For the various layouts, but this does not seem to be working. It keeps showing the xml file which is located in the **res/layout/** folder?

Any help would be appreciated!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use
    res/layout-xlarge-land
    res/layout-xlarge

Comment: Many thanks for the response! This seems to have solved the problem. How can I apply this to a style file?

Many thanks again!!

Comment: Use This Tutorial.Here you can know all info about it. [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491870/support-different-screen-sized/12491985#12491985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320

layout-small-ldpi
layout-small-land-ldpi

### Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432)

layout-ldpi
layout-land-ldpi

### Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480

layout-mdpi
layout-land-mdpi

### Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480

layout-large-mdpi
layout-large-land-mdpi

### High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854)

layout-hdpi
layout-land-hdpi

### Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res)

layout-xlarge
layout-xlarge-land

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** The sizes that you specify using these qualifiers are not the actual screen sizes. Rather, the sizes are for the width or height in dp units that are available to your activity's window. The Android system might use some of the screen for system UI (such as the system bar at the bottom of the screen or the status bar at the top), so some of the screen might not be available for your layout. Thus, the sizes you declare should be specifically about the sizes needed by your activity—the system accounts for any space used by system UI when declaring how much space it provides for your layout. Also beware that the Action Bar is considered a part of your application's window space, although your layout does not declare it, so it reduces the space available for your layout and you must account for it in your design.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts