# Android Galaxy S4 scaling images

Tags: android

I know that the nexus 7 automatically scales images to 1.33 their size. Does the s4 do this and if it does, what does the image get increased by?

Comment: This doc on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should be informative, especially the section on [Scaling Bitmap objects created at runtime](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#scaling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is: yes, the S4 (and all Android devices) do the auto-scaling of images as necessary based on their display pixel density and the density of the input image.  I believe that the S4 is classified as an "[xxhdpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH)" device which makes it 3x the standard "[mdpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_MEDIUM)" device.

A much more thorough discussion that explains all the details that go into these calculations and why they matter can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639150/3032.