# Which property do I consider for image resources: density or size?

Tags: android

I know when you want to include some images into your project, you put images into different versions of `'drawable'` folder according to different targets' densities. But what if we have two devices with the same destiny but different `SIZEs`?

Answer (score 0):

use the image for single Density
Because we create the Bitmap Drawable for Different Densities not for Different  Screen Sizes

Comment: ٍ Ok, that is exactly what I told :-) My question was: 'Why'? what if two devices have the sabre density, but different sizes?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani I dont Understand ,what u are exactly asking for but Drawable folder are for different Densities,please check the following link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638202/android-multiple-screen-sizes-with-same-density ]