# How to implement complex UI in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

How do I implement the complex UI as below

[image: Menu Screen]

I tried implementing this layout with combinations of different layout, experimenting with gravity and dynamic calculations

However As per my understanding it required few margin and padding hard coded in dp, which makes the UI unstable in different screen resolution

Can anyone help me guide on how can we implement this in efficient...

Also even xhdpi and xxhdpi layout are different in multiple device using same layout..can anyone tell why so?

Answer (score 1):

> However As per my understanding it required few margin and padding hard coded in dp, which makes the UI unstable in different screen resolution

Actually using margins and paddings in dp is a good practice to make your app look stable on different screen sizes.
Take a look at this question and answer:
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android/2025541#2025541)

Just make sure you have your margins and paddings in dimens.xml and create different dimens for other layouts (like sw600dp and sw720dp).

Comment: But then as per https://www.google.com/design/tool/devices/, I have to implement for all the resolutions?

Comment: Yes, you need to consider different groups of devices. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638202/android-multiple-screen-sizes-with-same-density it describes this topic in details.